# Can Blender's bundled "bfont" be used for commercially?

Tags: text-object

Blender, which I use to create my video intros, comes bundled with a bfont by default so the question is:

Is this font is free for commercial use and what type of license does this "bfont" font have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the other answers are about distributing the font file itself, the use of a font to display text in your final image is not the same as sharing the font file and is not affected by the licensing of the font file.

As explained further in this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_property_protection_of_typefaces) (that you should read)

> In the United States, the shapes of typefaces are not officially copyrightable, though they may be protected de facto by copyrights on computer code and trademarks on names.

which means the use of a font to draw text contained within an image does not cause copyright issues (some countries could have differing laws). While some fonts released under commercial licenses may restrict their use to people who paid for the font, the fonts included with blender are freely distributable and you are using them legally.

While there are other things to consider, like recreating some text that resembles a company logo can get you into trademark territory and some phrases have been trademarked etc, the general displaying of text in an image or video is not a copyright issue.

Answer (score 4):

The bfont is actually a modified [DejaVu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DejaVu_fonts) (which in turn is a modified Bitstream Vera).

You are free to use it commercially but:

- If you modify it, it has to be under a new name (it can't be called "bfont")
- You can't sell it by itself
- You have to include the copyright notice (found in `release/datafiles/LICENSE-bfont-ttf.txt`)

Check the license notice for more info.

Comment: no i do not have any plan to sell the font seprately i m talking about if i use bfont in my video intro which i made in blender and then use the intro video for commercial purposes

Answer (score 2):

***I am not a lawyer. This answer is not a substitute for reading the actual license file.***

Short answer: **Yes**

---

Bundled with the Blender binaries and source, you can find the licenses for all the software it depends on. For *bfont*, the file you want is called *LICENSE-bfont.ttf.txt*, in the same folder as the Blender executable in binary distributions.

It appears to be an entirely custom license, that, according to *my* interpretation, grants every one with all rights. Therefore, *I* believe it to be safe to use it commercially. (Might, however, not be the most.. appealing font :P)

Here is an excerpt of the license:

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
>   of the fonts accompanying this license ("Fonts") and associated
>   documentation files (the "Font Software"), to reproduce and distribute the
>   Font Software, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, merge,
>   publish, distribute, and/or sell copies of the Font Software, and to permit
>   persons to whom the Font Software is furnished to do so (...)